# How to pass variable values in series:[{data: }] object collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, series

Pass variable values in series:[{data: }]

In below snippet code I am getting value`2,10,2,2` in var ftes & this variable in need to pass in  `series:[{data: }]` but how ever it's not taking any effect in chart.

Anyone could guide me how to achieve this

In below snippet code getting value

```
function DreawLineChart(series, ssssss) {
var ftes = [];
    var fte = [];
    for (var i in ssssss) {
          fte = new Array(ssssss[i]);
        //alert(fte);
        ftes.push(fte)
    } alert(ftes);


//In below code i have to pass varibale.


        Highcharts.chart('container2', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Employee FTE'        },
                subtitle: {
                    //text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    //categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                    categories: series
                },     
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'FTE'
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    line: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        enableMouseTracking: false
                    }
                },
                /* series: [{
                     name: 'Singapore',
                     data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

                 }, {
                     name: 'New Zealand',
                     data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
                 }] */
                   series: [{
                  name: 'Singapore',
                  data: ftes  //Here i am passing the variable
                  }]

            });
        }
    }
```

o/p of   console.log(ssssss);

(4) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
0
:
["2"]
1
:
["10"]
2
:
["2"]
3
:
["2"]

Comment: Could you show `ssssss` variable? Is that `2,10,2,2` a string? Array of numbers? Array of Strings? Use `console.log`, not `alert`.

Comment: success: function (Result) {
                    var data = [];
                    var data2 = [];
                    for (var i in Result) {                       
                        var serie = new Array(Result[i].MONTH);
                        data.push(serie);                      
                         var fte = new Array(Result[i].MONTHLY_TOTAL_FTE);                    
                         data2.push(fte);                     
                    }   DreawLineChart(data,data2);

Comment: my ajax function

Comment: I mean result from your ajax, not the ajax function. Simply replace `alert(ftes);` with `console.log(ssssss)` and let us know what you have in web tools.

Comment: o/p (4) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
0
:
["2"]
1
:
["10"]
2
:
["2"]
3
:
["2"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

we need to use `JSON.parse()`

```
data: JSON.parse("[" + myJString + "]")
```